# CTE instead of temp table due to "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

When I tried to use a child sproc in a parent sproc I got:

```
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested
```

Hence, I started to repeat code in a CTE rather than invoking the child sproc. This is the code:

```
SET @Sql = N'
;WITH MonthsAndYears AS
(
    SELECT 
        TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1) 
        [TheMonth] = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate)),
        [TheYear]  = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate)),
        [Date]  = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate)), 0)
    FROM [master].dbo.spt_values 
    WHERE [type] = N''P''
)
...
```

Previously I used:

```
CREATE TABLE #MonthsAndYears ([Month] INT, [Year] int, [Date] SMALLDATETIME)
INSERT INTO #MonthsAndYears EXEC Logi_GetMonthsAndYears @FromDate, @ToDate
```

and referred to #MonthsAndYears in my succeeding cte code (the sproc does exactly the same as the cte). The problem is that when I use the cte approach without temp table the query executes much slower. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of SQL Server. It had been rased as a bug/improvement with Microsoft many years ago.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/294571/improve-insert-exec
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/272133/cannot-have-nested-insert-exec

Therefore you'll need to use workarounds. Some workarounds are discussed in this article:

[How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Comment: Yeah I was aware of this thanks. Found a solution - I just created a dedicated table for the data and filled it up to a very large date. I will accept your answer as it may point others in the right direction.